# Field Type list in module creation

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to adapt the next code from the book:
http://www.amazon.es/Drupal-Development-Experts-Voice-Source/dp/1430228385/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327316185&sr=8-1

```
function _job_post_installed_fields() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'job_post_company' => array(
      'field_name'  => 'job_post_company',
      'label'       => $t('Company posting the job listing'),
      'type'        => 'text',
), );
}
/**
 * Return a structured array defining the field instances associated with this content type.
*/
function _job_post_installed_instances() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'job_post_company' => array(
      'field_name'  => 'job_post_company',
'type'
'label'
'widget'
'type' ),
  => 'text',
  => $t('Company posting the job listing'),
  => array(
=> 'text_textfield',
      'display' => array(
        'example_node_list' => array(
          'label'       => $t('Company posting the job listing'),
          'type' => 'text',
        ),
), ),
); }
```

But I can find anywhere a list of types I kind use instead of "text".

My question is:
Can you help me find a place where I can find a list of possible images?
How that code would be if I wanted to create an image field, or a tag list field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For field definitions, I find that the easiest thing to do, is to create the field in the UI and fetch the definition using `field_info_field` and `field_info_instance` and then dump the variable using the devel module (`dpm`) oe something similar.

Alternatively you could browse code, field types are defined in `hook_field_info` and widgets are defined in `hook_field_widget_info` (the form for the field) and formatters are defined in `hook_field_formatter_info` (how fields are rendered).

Comment: Ok, there was a list there, but I thought I could find more info on the Docs, thanks

Comment: @Googletorp ITS THE LEGEND! =D

Answer (score 0):

I do what googletorp mentions often as well.

I dont remember a drupal.org page that lists the field types possible, but there are many blog posts that talk about this topic, for example from http://ado.io/blog/drupal-7/working-programmatically-with-fields-in-drupal-7

A brief list from that blog post gives us:

```
Field types
Field types out-of-the-box are listed below, machine name of the field type is the highlighted one. You’ll need this later when it’s time to programmatically create one.

BOOLEAN :: list_boolean
DECIMAL :: number_decimal
FILE :: file
FLOAT :: number_float
IMAGE :: image
INTEGER :: number_integer
LIST (FLOAT) :: list_float
LIST (INTEGER) :: list_integer
LIST (TEXT) :: list_text
LONG TEXT :: text_long
LONG TEXT AND SUMMARY :: text_with_summary
TERM REFERENCE :: taxonomy_term_reference
TEXT :: text
```